# Please help me in this question.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta} + \frac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin^2\beta} =1$
PROVE THAT 
$\frac{\sin^2\beta}{\cos^2\alpha} + \frac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin^2\alpha} = 1$
I tried a lot by using $\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta =1$

Comment: is $cis^2(\alpha)=\cos^2(\alpha)$?

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta$ angles of a triangle?

Comment: Perhaps the supposition is
$$\frac{sin^2\alpha}{cos^2\beta} + \frac{cos^2\alpha}{sin^2\beta} =1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner (first comment) it seems extremely likely yes as 'o' and 'i' keys are adjacent - so this is just a typo (second comment) no, probably just seperate unknown angles.

Answer (score 1):

HInt:

Assuming the condition to be

$$\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta}+\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}=1$$

Use $\cos^2\alpha=1-\sin^2\alpha$ to get

$$1=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta}+\dfrac{1-\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}$$

$$\iff\csc^2\beta-1=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}-\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin^2\alpha}=\dfrac{\cos2\beta}{\cos^2\beta}$$

$$\iff\sin^2\alpha=\dfrac{\cos^4\beta}{\cos2\beta}\iff\cos^2\alpha=-\dfrac{\sin^4\beta}{\cos2\beta}$$

Now replace values of $\sin^2\alpha,\cos^2\alpha$ in

$$\frac{\sin^2\beta}{\cos^2\alpha} + \frac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin^2\alpha}$$

Comment: (to me at least) it is very unclear how you made the first two $\iff$s. Perhaps you could iron them out a little

Comment: @RhysHughes,   Use $\cos^2\alpha=1-\sin^2\alpha$ to express $\sin^2\lpha$ in terms of $beta$